# using mutt to send mail via python not working

Tags: python, email, mutt

Here is a python script I am running from two different machines `A` and `B`:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.Popen('echo "Body of mail" | mutt -s "Subject of mail" -- myaddress@abcd.in', shell=True)
a.communicate()
```

I am receiving the required email when I run this script from machine `A` but I'm not receiving the required email when I run it from machine `B`. Any idea why this should happen, even when `mutt` is installed in both machines? Is there something else I need to check or configure properly?

Comment: Did you try running the command directly from the command line on machine B?  Can you receive other e-mails sent from B?

Comment: Yes, tried directly from shell. Working for `A` but not for `B`

Comment: Any reason why this must be happening? Anything I need to check for running that command in order for it to work?

Comment: `echo` and pipe does not work with all mutt version IIRC. You can use something like `mutt -s "Subject of mail" -- myaddress@abcd.in < /path/to/body.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Please try with the command without `--`, like following.

```
echo "Body of mail" | mutt -s "Subject of mail" myaddress@abcd.in
```